# how to make the footer to align in 1 line?

Tags: php, html, css, yii

Working with Yii framework, I have a footer that lookslike this:
[image]

with the following CODE:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_left">
        <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
            'id'=>'footerID',
            'items' => array(
                array('label'    => 'About', 'id' =>'leftFooter', 'url'  => array('/site/page', 'view' => 'about')),
                array('label'    => 'Help', 'id' =>'MiddleFooter','url'  => array('#')),
                array('label'    => 'Contact', 'id' =>'rightFooter','url'    => array('/site/contact')),
            ),
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_right"><?php echo Yii::t('footer', 'Copyright'); ?> &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php echo Yii::t('footer', Yii::t('footer', 'Momentum Technologies Ltd')); ?></div>
</div>
<?php
// no need to access the rights module if user is not logged in yet
//if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest !== true)//TODO && Yii::app()->user->checkAccess(Rights::module()->superuserName))
{
    $translate = Yii::app()->translate;
    echo $translate->dropdown();

    if ($translate->hasMessages())
    {
        echo $translate->translateLink('Translate (newPage)');
        echo $translate->translateDialogLink('Translate(dialog)', 'Translate page title') . ' | ';
    }

    echo $translate->editLink(Yii::t('translatemodule', 'Edit translations page')) . ' | ';
    echo $translate->missingLink('Missing translations page') . '<br/>';
}
?>
<?php ZHtml::commonJsMessage(); ?>
<!-- page -->
```

I am trying to get these in one line using my css:

```
#footer
{
    /*padding: 10px;
    margin: 70px -20px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #C9E0ED;
    background-color: rgb(122, 185, 240);*/
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #C9E0ED;
}
#footer.ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

with unsuccessful results. can u help me out here?
I want about/help and contact to be in 1 line.

Comment: Put them all in one div?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't require `#footer.ul` to be set as inline-block itself.

What you want to do is set the list items themselves to either inline or inline-block:

```
#footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is generating un-ordered lists then the style should be applied to the `li`s. Should be -

```
#footer ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your css file-

```
#footer ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```